# WebAPI Method Reads Multiple Actions Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**I have two methods, both of which work perfectly one their own** (i.e. when one of them is commented out) but when both are in the program, I get this error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple
>   actions were found that match the request: \r\nAddUserToGroup on type
>   WebAPI_POC1.Controllers.Admin.AccountController\r\nGetRolesForUser on
>   type
>   WebAPI_POC1.Controllers.Admin.AccountController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()"}

Here are the two methods in my AccountController:

```
public bool AddUserToGroup(AddUserToGroupBindingModel model)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return result;
    }

    var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserEmail);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var tmp = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.GroupName);
        result = ((tmp.Succeeded) ? true : false);
    }

    return result;
}

[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<string> GetRolesForUser(GetUserGroupsBindingModel model)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserEmail);
    List<string> roles = new List<string>();

    if (user != null)
    {
        roles = new List<string>(UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id));
    }

    return roles;
}
```

**Important Detail:** I am using a different Route config like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(config));
```

The code is from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx which I implemented so that I could use namespaces to separate my different controllers.

Why can't WebAPI find these two different controller actions which have different names, different signatures and different return types?

Comment: I'm guessing that `Get` is a verb.

Comment: Your comments for the method say `api/Account/GetUserRoles` but your request is for `/api/` **admin** `/account/GetRolesForUser` .  I see you change the name from `GetRolesForUser` , but the extra `/admin/` is what I'm hung up on.  You could also try changing to parameters to `([FromUri]string userEmail)`

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried changing it to just `RolesForUser?userEmail=alice` to alleviate both the `Get` verb and the ampersand, but it still gives me a 404.

Comment: @Tom sorry I removed the comments.  I have a namespace prefix before the controller name (admin).  Like I said, the other method works fine; it hits the breakpoint and everything when debugging, just not this one, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check your WebApiConfig, it probably has something like this?

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Have you tried your get operation like this?
"/api/admin/account/GetRolesForUser/alice@wonderland.com"

If that works maybe adding a [FromUrl] to your operation like so:

```
public bool GetRolesForUser([FromUrl] string userEmail)
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter as he is using attribute routing.

Comment: I am using a different Route config.  I updated the question with it.

Comment: hmm, that does seem to change the ballgame a little bit user8472, are you sure removing that line doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing my route like so.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{namespace}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(config));
```

Comment: Could you share your IHttpControllerSelector implementation? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Gandarez It's a lot like this https://github.com/valeravorobjev/SampleHttpControllerSelector/blob/master/SampleHttpControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

Answer (score 0):

[Route("api/Controller-Name/Method-Name")]
[HttpPost]

Comment: Can you share some more context?